# VLOOKUP returns "N/A#" until manual intervention

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am stumped. I use VLOOKUP (inside a loop) to plug values into cells but get "N/A#". However, if I click the cell that is being looked up (the first parameter of VLOOKUP), then click in the formula bar, then click anywhere else, the VLOOKUP'd values appear. How do I get it to retrieve values without manual clicking?

```
Dim ii As Long
ii = 1            ' 1 is hdr row
For Each cel In Range("J2:J114").Columns.Cells
   ii = ii + 1
   cel.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D" & ii & ",Sheet2!$D$2:$V$200,4,FALSE)"
Next cel
```

Comment: Is there a worksheet named "Sheet2" (not `Sheets(2)`) in workbook? Also, is there data in current sheet's D column AND Sheet2's D column?

Comment: A minor point -- there is no reason for `Columns` in `Range(:J2:J114").Columns.Cells` simply use `.Cells`

Comment: Is this code running while Sheet2 is the active sheet? If so -- you are modifying the range of the lookup while iterating over it (since J is between D and V). I'm not sure why that would cause what you see, but it seems like the results would be unpredictable. Perhaps the fix is as simple as putting `Application.Calculate` after `Next cel`.

Comment: 1) Did you turn of the automatic calculation? 
2) You should maybe define cel as a range

Comment: I found the solution. I looped through the column containing the value to be searched and reset the cel.Value and the VLOOKUP worked. That must have done something similar to what clicking in the formula bar was doing.